# function returns vector with true or false value

Tags: r, function

```
 Q1.25%  Q3.75% iqr.75% 
   -4.4     4.9     9.3 


outlier<-function(x){
  Q<-quartiles(x)
  min_outlier<-Q[1]-1.5*Q[3]  #outlier based on 25% quartiles 
  min_outlier
  max_outlier<-Q[2]+1.5*Q[3] #outlier based on 75% quartiles
  max_outlier
  x<-vector()
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (max_outlier< x[i] || min_outlier>x[i]) {x[i]<-c("true")}
     else{x[i]<-c("false")}
    x<-x[i]
  i<-i+1
    }
  return(x)
}
```

#function should return x as true or false values. Error in if (max_outlier < x[i] || min_outlier > x[i]) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `for` loop to check every individual value. Also do you mean `quantile` instead of `quartiles`.

```
outlier<-function(x){
  Q <- quartiles(x)
  min_outlier<-Q[1]-1.5*Q[3]  
  max_outlier<-Q[2]+1.5*Q[3] 
  x > max_outlier | x < min_outlier
}
```

Comment: Thank you , quartiles(x) is the function that I wrote for quantiles. but didn't use the R quantiles() function.  I need the output of the entire vector to check in the if statement and come back as a vector of true or false values. So I thought I need to have a for loop.